# How to assign didSelectRowAtIndexPath in Tableview cells subview item

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have 2 problem and i am totally confuse. please help me

1) I face one problem that i want to assign click listener to image view which is inside of my subview and that subview is with in cell of `UITableView`.

In my tableview cell there are two image-view i want to give them click listener and also identify them like which image-view is clicked on which row etc etc.

if i write `scrollview.userinteractionEnable=YES;` than my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` Not responds.
i know its because of subview.
But if i change `scrollview.userinteractionEnable=NO;` than my `didselectrowatIndexpath` code executes. but scrollview does not scroll to horizontal..

What do i do ? I want horizontal scroll plus Image-view click Listener on both ImageView.

** Solve click problem by crating scrollview sub class**

This is my Customcell class

```
cellScrollViewClass *scrollView = [[cellScrollViewClass alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,430,187)];
     scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * 3,scrollView.frame.size.height);
    scrollView.scrollEnabled=YES;
    scrollView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = scrollView.frame.size;

        if(i==2) // to check Last item must be train Engine   
        {
            UIView *EngineView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
            UIImageView *engineImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-112.5, 6, 430, 180)];
            UIImage *Image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backengine.png"];
            engineImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            engineImageView.image = Image;
            [EngineView addSubview:engineImageView];
            [scrollView addSubview:EngineView];  // add 3rd imageview that is Train Engine to end of scrollview
        }
        else{ // Not equal to 2 than it must be wagon of train. 

    UIView *wagon = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
    UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wagon.png"]];
    wagon.backgroundColor = background;

    UIView *videoviewContainer = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 40, 220 , 200)];

    UIImageView *videoImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 220, 100)];
    UIImage *bgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"video.png"];
    videoImageView.image = bgImage;
    videoviewContainer.contentMode = UIViewContentModeLeft; // set Video Image view to left hand side of wagon UIView
            videoImageView.tag=2;


    [videoviewContainer addSubview:videoImageView];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapGestureCaptured:)];
    [videoImageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    [videoImageView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
    [videoImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    UIView *textUiView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(238,28, 150 , 187)];
    textUiView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRight;
    UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(28,10, 150 , 87)];
    label.text=@"This is testing text for IOS app to check line are aligned or not and to check video image and nested views for UIviews";
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
    label.numberOfLines = 4;
    [textUiView addSubview:label];

    [wagon addSubview:textUiView];
    [wagon addSubview:videoviewContainer];
    [scrollView addSubview:wagon];
    [self.contentView addSubview:scrollView];
  }
  }
  }
    return self;
  }


  - (void)singleTapGestureCaptured:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
    {

     NSLog(@"Touch event on view %d",gesture.view.tag);
     }
```

And I created Scrollview subclass like this..

```
@implementation cellScrollViewClass
  - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
    {
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
   if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    NSLog(@"You are in scrollview");
        }
   return self;
     }
```

IS this one is right method of Implementation?

[image]

Any Help is Appreciated . Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `UITapGestureRecognizer`. Create and attach a tap gesture recogniser to each image view when you create it. Also set the tag of the image view when you create it so you can identify which one it is on the cell.

When you get the callback from the recogniser you can get the tag by:

```
recogniser.view.tag
```

And you can get the table view cell by looping on the superview until you find a table view cell class:

```
UIView *superView = recogniser.view.superview;
while (superView != nil && ![superView isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
    superView = superView.superview;
}
```

Then you can get the index path from the table view using

```
[tableView indexPathForCell:superView];
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the on click listener for `UIImageView` have a category of it & use `touches begin method` and delegate callback to 'tableViewController'.

Use tags to identify which image is clicked & which row.

To avoid overlap, if the cell us already allocated just remove the previous images to do this have a `else` condition.

Comment: Can you please guide me..i am new to IOS development.. do you have any tutorial or sample for this?

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement the UIScrollView delegate callbacks and check what kind of scroll the user is doing (horizontal scroll or vertical scroll) and then changing the tableview or the scrollview offset manually, thats pretty much the only way i see this...

as for your image you need to set a UIButton for everyImage and link them to a selector, then you can use the tag of the button to know what image it was.

Comment: can you please guide me to implement Uibutton and selector or image view..as i am new to iOS ..

Comment: sorry, i saw only now your request, i don't know if you still need the answer but anyway here it is.

[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(yourSelector:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(void)yourSelector:(UIButton*)sender
{
if(sender.tag == 0)
{
...
}
...
}

it's something like this in code ;) if you're using interface builder you can bind the button directly to your function ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can add a custom button over the imageview with same frame of image view and the you can add the selector on the button.

Comment: Just replace your imageview by uibutton and addselector on the uibutton you can set the image as
[uibutton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forControlState:UIControlStateNormal];
[uibutton addTarget:self action:@selecotr(btnPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventsTouchUpInside];

Answer (score -1):

For handling gestures on UIImageView make sure that the UIImageView that you are using has the  `userInteractionEnable = YES` by default is set to `NO`

Comment: dude i know that but my problem is if i so scrollview.userinteraction=NO; than horizontal scroll wont work. and if i set scroll view user-- =YES; than imageview Useinteraction wont work